# Import Error: No module named pyrebase

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, importerror

I have a problem with importing pyrebase on my `raspberrypi`. 
In the picture you see the ErrorCode. Before I installed `pyrebase` with the command: `sudo pip install pyrebase`

[image: ErrorCode]

Comment: After you installed `pyrebase`, are you still getting this error?

Comment: yes. I installed it before.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple python versions installed, then there may be problem that it faces on which version of pyrebase to install. Check which version of python or pip is working on your machine.

```
pip --version
```

If you are working with the right python version try pip freeze or pip list to see the list of installed libraries, and check if pyrebase is there. Install it if your python version is 3.x using:

```
pip3 install pyrebase
```

If python version is 2.x use:

```
pip install pyrebase
```

Hope it helps.